# Is there a comprehensive overview of food colors?

Tags: chemistry, color, additives

I found a small list of [food additives compiled by the FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/FoodAdditivesIngredients/ucm094211.htm#types), but it looks rather incomplete and somewhat unspecific.

For example, some colors like gold (probably the real thing) <strike>or silver (E171 - titan dioxide)</strike> are not listed, and it looks like not all possible variants for a color are shown.

Are there exhaustive lists of color additives, preferably with their chemical name or something, for North America, for Europe and Australia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FDA has a page for [color additives](http://www.fda.gov/ForIndustry/ColorAdditives/ColorAdditiveInventories/ucm106626.htm) and a separate one for [food additives](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/FoodAdditivesIngredients/ucm091048.htm). They're fairly concise; they refer to but don't link to the complete documents. (I'll try and find those at some point.)

For the EU, I believe you want E numbers. There's actually a pretty solid [E number article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number). On the EU site, there's a [list of authorized food additives](http://ec.europa.eu/food/food/fAEF/additives/lists_authorised_fA_en.htm) page which further links to a database and full document. (You can find a lot more copies of this kind of thing by searching for E numbers on Google.)

Answer (score 3):

The EU has a list of food additives in which everything is given a number (so you don't have to deal with companies trying to hide things using alternate names):

- https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/sanco_foods/main/?sector=FAD

Many of the colorings are under [Group II](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/sanco_foods/main/?event=substance.view&identifier=2) and [Group III](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/sanco_foods/main/?event=substance.view&identifier=3), but many other items (eg, fruit and vegetable juices) can be used as coloring, so you can't just look in those categories.